# Detecting the data type by reading a string

Tags: c

So I've wondered, what would be the simplest way to check for user input (stdin).
I came to conclusion, ideally it would be to scanf an user input and print out the results.

Though now I'm somewhat confused, about how should I do this. Here's what I was thinking:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

char input[30];    

 printf("Please enter text\n");
 scanf("%s", &input);

 ...
```

So here's the part I can't really wrap my head around of. So what I'd like to do, is run through the entire word (input), character by character.

Basically, if the string consits of only numbers (0-9), I'd like the input to be identified as a number. Otherwise, detect it as a string.

I've done a fair bit of research (although keep in mind I'm an absolute beginner), there is a way with strcmp() function, but I'd prefer avoiding other libraries, such as string.h altogether and just do it the simple way, as I've tried to explain.

Comment: Let's begin with passing `char*` instad of `char(*)[30]` to `scanf`. SImply speaking, use `input` instead of `&input` as `scanf`'s argument.

Comment: "*I came to conclusion, ideally it would be to scanf an user input ...*" I object and claim it's `fgets()`.

Comment: dont use & before input in scanf as it is a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int checkIfNumber(const char *word) {
    /* check until the string ends */
    while (*word != '\0') {
        /* return 0 if the character isn't a number */
        if (*word < '0' || '9' < *word) return 0;
        /* proceed to the next character */
        word++;
    }
    /* no characters other than numbers found */
    return 1;
}

int main(void){

    char input[30];

    printf("Please enter text\n");
    scanf("%29s", input);

    if(checkIfNumber(input)) {
        printf("%s is number\n", input);
    } else {
        printf("%s is string\n", input);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that character code for numbers are continuous in C, so this range-based method is useful for checking if a character is a number (decimal digit).
This method may not work for alphabets, especially on systems on which non-ASCII character code is used.

[N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 5.2.1 Character sets

> In both the source and execution basic character sets, the
>   value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than
>   the value of the previous.